# Soap UI Splitting property transfer results

Tags: soapui

Can anybody help with splitting results from a property transfer?

i.e.

If my response is:

```
`<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<CurrenciesResponse xmlns="http://webservices.cloanto.com/currencyserver/">
<CurrenciesResult>AED;AFN;ARS;AUD;AZN;BBD;</CurrenciesResult>
</CurrenciesResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`
```

and I have a Property Transfer of

```
`declare namespace soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace ns1='http://webservices.cloanto.com/currencyserver/';
//ns1:CurrenciesResult`
```

I get an expected transfer to Currency1 of 
AED;AFN;ARS;AUD;AZN;BBD

Now is there an easy way for me to split the properties returned so I could store them in

Currency1 AED

Currency2 AFN

etc

Any ideas or help very much appreciated!

Comment: Can the minus voter please explain if there is not enough information here or is it minus because its too difficult??

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Transfer the XPath values into a Property, then use Groovy script to:

- Read the property value, store as string.
- Split string by semi-colon and store into an array.
- Create new Property for each array item.

Then use each Property as/where you need it.